# what is output voltage Vo in steady state?

Tags: diodes

[image]

**If looking to symmetry in the circuit, the both terminal of resistor would be at same voltage? I am confused to deal with this circuit and how to start the procedure? Please help me **

Comment: You are right about the symmetry...

Comment: The output is zero. Trick question.

Comment: It doesn't matter the frequecies, component values ...: in a totally symetric circuit, voltage between symetric points is always zero. Wants the author draw one of the diodes in the opossite direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vo is always equal to 0. If the two diodes are the same, they will drive the current at the same time. Thus, R+ is equal to R- at anytime.

Vo = VR+ - VR- = 0. You are right ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 0, and with questions like these it can be helpful to draw it in a different way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9tIzI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this orientation, its *slightly* easier to see the relevant symmetry.

Comment: Really easier? On the original a simple horizontal line in the middle is forming an axis of a symmetry. Where the axis is here?

Comment: This is easier for me, because it follows a more familiar topology (voltage source on the left) and because it feels easier to analyse the separate symmetrical parts. It's also much easier to see the current paths (I think)

Comment: Certainly, if the capacitors were different values, this is how you would analyse it.

Comment: A downvote seems sort of harsh...

Comment: I wouldn't downvote for that.

Comment: +1 just cos I could :) down-vote did seem pointless, even if it did take me a few moments to see it was the same circuit.